# How can I have a form send users to a different page after submitting a form?

Tags: javascript

I created a web to lead form from salesforce that creates a case, when the user submits the form they are taken to thanks.html.

I added a new field and need the user to be sent two one of two forms depending on the selection they have made.

Example:

```
<option value="Website Issue">Website Issue</option>

<option value="Other">Other</option>
```

If the user selects Website issue and submits the form they should be sent to thanks1.html
If the user selects Other and submits the form they should be send to thanks2.html

I am currently using retURL to send users to a single page no matter the response on the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't have this level of control with the web to lead form - you can only define the page that you wish to send the user to, and no information about the lead is retained for use by that page.  If you have access to JavaScript, you can rewrite the hidden input field that is used to generate the retUrl value based on the user selection.

The way that I've handled this in the past is to create a Visualforce page to capture a lead and make this available through an unauthenticated Force.com site.  This page can be styled appropriately for the web site it appears in and embedded using an iframe.  This way you have full control over what happens after the form has been submitted, plus you can use an extension controller for any additional business logic required.